# External USB hard drives don't work with Windows 7, but with Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, usb-flash-drive

On a machine, I dual-boot Windows XP and Windows 7 (both 32-bit).

**Several** external hard drives **work well under Windows XP**, but under **Windows 7 none of them is shown as a drive** in Explorer.

The only thing that happens under Windows 7 is: after plugging in the USB cable, the system recognizes a plugged device and shows the "safely remove hardware" toolbar-icon (which refers to some Bridge device).

What can be the reason?
What additional information could I provide to clarify the problem?

Comment: Do they show up in Computer Management (Control panel, Admin tools)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

right click on **Computer** > **Manage** > **Disk Management**

if the drive is showing there, assgin a drive letter.